# Scaffold migration with context key change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have restructured my project which led to a change of namespace name of the database context and associated Code First configuration. At that point, I've had one scaffolded migration, "InitialCreate" and thus my database's `__MigrationHistory` table contained a single row with some `MigrationId` and a `ContextKey` containing the namespace name and class name of the `Configuration` class.

After I've moved things around, executing `Get-Migrations` returned no results, after changing the `ContextKey` as per my colleague's advice, the "InitialCreate" migration was correctly enumerated.

What steps should I have taken during the changes so the continuity of my migrations wasn't broken, preventing the need to rename the `ContextKey` by hand? Obviously, that's no big deal for one applied migration, however it'd be a huge pain to do for dozens of applied migrations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was stuck in this for a long time and asked-and-answered-it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752406/enity-framework-6-0-0-0-unable-to-generate-an-explicit-migration-with-code). In the EF docs you can find the explanation about context keys [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations).You should create custom migration configuration like this :

```
 public class MyMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyMigrationContext>
{
    public MyMigrationConfiguration ()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        MigrationsNamespace = "My.Migrations.Assembly";
        MigrationsDirectory = "My/Migrations/Directory";
        ContextKey = "MyContexKey"; // You MUST set this for every migration context
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've learnt that the `DbMigrationsConfiguration{TDbContext}` class has a property called `ContextKey` (EF6 and its "multi-tenant migrations" feature) which allows me to explicitly set the context key. This property would be set if I used the `-ContextTypeName` parameter of the [`Enable-Migrations`](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Enable-Migrations) command in Package Manager Console.

It doesn't seem as though the context key can be altered once the first migration is applied, however with the option to set the context key this way after the configuration class type name has changed, it is almost unnecessary if you can tolerate some disparity in your database.

Answer (score 3):

I had two separated database projects - one containing model and mapping, other one containing only migration configuration and all migrations. I've merged project containing migrations into project containing model, etc.

Finally I solved problem with impossibility to add new migration or keep database up to date or migrating schema to previous state by making those steps:

- I changed namespaces in merged project to all migrations and configuration itself to new namespace value.
- I executed following statement against database:

  ```
  USE [DatabaseName]

  GO

  UPDATE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]
     SET [ContextKey] = N'NewNamepacePlusConfigurationClassName'      
   WHERE ContextKey= N'NamepacePlusConfigurationClassName'

  GO
  ```
- I build project containing migrations with configuration

Now everything works as expected, I'm even able to change schema backwards using statement

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration PreviousMigration
```

Comment: what if the column doesn't exist in _MirtationHistory?